STUFF XML with openquery is matching on values that should've been filtered out in the where clause?
I typically use STUFF and XML to concatenate multiple values where I'm expecting one distinct row, e.g.



Category
Product




Fruit
Apple


Food
Apple



select distinct
t1.Product
, Categories = STUFF((
     select distinct ' / ' + t1a.Category 
     from table1 t1a
     where
     t1a.Product = t1.product
     for xml path('')),1,3,'')
from table1 t1

Output:



Product
Categories




Apple
Food / Fruit




With that out of the way, I'm trying to do that same function, but in a more complex query involving linked servers. I originally had a query that joined 2 tables across 2 servers, but it was way too slow, so I discovered openquery, which seems to be OK and is returning me the results way, way faster, but I'm finding some duplicate rows because of one column with differing values, so I'm trying to squash them into a single row with the STUFF.
The awkward thing is that the 2 tables I'm trying to compare/link, one of them is implemented normally in terms of column data types. The other is implemented very poorly. On the poor table, they're just varchar columns, and the table is a bit of a dumping ground for data, so one column which might be 90% numeric values, the rest will have alphabetical values, or other characters, or just a blank value (not null, just '').
So I'm trying to pre-filter this poor table so that it joins/matches to the good table, but no matter what I try, it seems to be trying to pull ALL rows from the bad table, which returns a

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'ABC' to data type int


Below is where I'm up to at the moment, but still the same issue
with src as (
select * from openquery(
[LinkedServer], 'select * from [LinkedServer].[a].[b].[good_table] where ID in (
select ID from [LocalServer].[a].[b].[bad_table]
where
ID not like ''%[A-Z]%'' and ID not like ''%.%'' and ID not like ''''
)')
)
select distinct
Dates = STUFF((
    select distinct ' / ' + bt2.aDate
    from (
            select distinct 
            convert(nvarchar(MAX), bt1.[date], 23) as 'aDate'
            , bt1.ID
            from bad_table bt1
            where
            bt1.ID not like '%[A-Z]%' and bt1.ID not like '%.%' and bt1.ID not like ''
        ) bt2
        where
        bt2.id = s1.id
        for xml path('')),1,3,'')
, s1.ID
, s1.*
from src s1

Returns

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'ABC' to data type int.

I'm probably getting caught out by the order of operation or something, but how can it possibly still try to match on the non-numeric rows when I'm filtering them out with CTEs and subqueries within subqueries? The only thing that remotely works is when I add in
bt2.id = s1.id and bt2.ID not in ('.', 'abc','hhh','WWQS')

Which I don't find a good solution.

Please read How to create an example. Why don't you use STRING_AGG?

Consider using TRY_CAST or TRY_CONVERT to avoid unsafe conversion errors that are plan-dependent.

You apologize for such a long question, but really we only need half the information, a simple [mre]

This is the third time (at least) someone has asked this today. Simple answer there is no such thing as pre-filtering unless you put the results in a temp table. Otherwise the engine will determine the most efficient way to retry the data which has not relationship with how you write the query

Please read this answer, because it gives you all the relevant theory https://stackoverflow.com/a/78611613/1127428
